# How to use FileFilter with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to use jFileChooser to only import images and pdf to my app. 
I tried to use FileFilter to filter the file types. But it didn't work. Can anyone give me some sample code for it.

Comment: *"Can anyone give me some sample code for it."*  SO is not a code factory.  Show some effort if you expect help.  1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: sorry Andrew Thompson im new for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use FileFilter with FileNameExtensionFilter.
here is a sample code.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");


   FileFilter type1 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png", "JPG", "PNG");
   FileFilter type2 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF Documents", "pdf");
   FileFilter type3 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("All Files", ".");


   chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(type1);
   chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(type2);
   chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(type3);

   chooser.setFileFilter(type1); // Initial filter setting
   chooser.setFileFilter(type2);
   chooser.setFileFilter(type3);

   chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
   chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

   int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
   if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
       lblFileName.setText(f.toString());
       if (chooser.getFileFilter() == type1) {
           //you can add code for file type 1
       } else if (chooser.getFileFilter() == type2) {
           //you can add code for file type 2
       }
   }
```

Comment: Don't use `==` for object comparison, use `.equals(..)` (even if rep-whoreing off bad questions that should be closed).